# How to extract Scenario outline Examples values in After hook

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

For reporting purposes I need to determine Scenario outline Examples in Cucumber (JVM6).
Looks like there is no obvious way to do it other than doing it directly in StepDefs.

Lets assume I have scenario like this:

```
   Scenario Outline: Name
     When I call cat by name "<catName>"
     Then It responses

     Examples:
       | catName |
       | Fluffy  |
       | Snowy   |
```

I would like to do something like:

```
@After
public void report(Scenario scenario) {
   List<Examples> examples = scenario.getExamples();
}
```

Unfortunately adding examples value extraction StepDefs is not an option. As well as adding new technical step.

Comment: Is this reporting intended to be part of reporting on the test execution or are you trying to get a list of all examples.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje better would be to have current example, but list would do as well.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me more about the report you are trying to make? It matters for the answer